# Having issue with my Wordpress + Woocommerce site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

My WordPress website is having this issue. May I know how to solve it?

Deprecated: Function is_admin_or_embed_page is deprecated since version 6.3! Use \Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\PageController::is_admin_or_embed_page() instead. in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5379

Answer (score 0):

You can try upgrading your woocommerce, first make a backup.

But this deprecated function warning is not serious. You can ask to your host provider about disabling PHP Warnings.